I need help in finding my mistake in this prolog code
Im building an interface with the objective of diagnosing someone and providing a form of treatment including the methods of treatment, with the cost and duration of it. I start by providing a list of symptoms and asking the user if they have it (insert 1) or if they don't (insert 2). Then I associate the list of symptoms with a certain disease and I provide the information on the treatment.
When I run the code on SWI-prolog it get's stuck on the answer to the first question and does not move forward to the second one.
Can anyone tell me what my mistake was?
This is the code I have where I set my rules:
:- dynamic (fact/1), [interface].
:- dynamic (demo/1).
  
%A simple backward chaining rule interpreter
:-  op( 800, fx, if).
:-  op( 700, xfx, then).
:-  op( 300, xfy, or).
:-  op( 200, xfy, and).

demo( Q)  :- 
   fact( Q).

demo( Q)  :-
   if Condition then Q, %A relevant rule   
   demo( Condition). %whose condition is true 

demo( Q1 and Q2)  :-
   demo( Q1),
   demo( Q2).

demo( Q1 or Q2)  :-
   demo( Q1)
   ;
   demo( Q2).

%Simple forward chaining in Prolog

demo:- new_derived_fact( P),             %A new fact
   !,
   write( 'Derived: '), write( P), nl,
   assert( fact( P)),
   demo.
demo:- write( 'No more facts').          %All facts derived

new_derived_fact( Concl)  :-
   if Cond then Concl,               %A rule
   \+ fact( Concl),                 %Rule's conclusion not yet a fact
   composed_fact( Cond).             %Condition true?

composed_fact( Cond)  :-
   fact( Cond).                      %Simple fact

composed_fact( Cond1 and Cond2)  :-
   composed_fact( Cond1),
   composed_fact( Cond2).            %Both conjuncts true

composed_fact( Cond1 or Cond2)  :-
   composed_fact( Cond1)
   ;
   composed_fact( Cond2).

%Associating symptoms with diseases

if febre and tosse and dor_de_cabeca and cansaco then gripe.
if cansaco and palidez then anemia.
if dificuldade_respiratoria and tosse then asma.
if dor_abdominal and nausea and diarreia and vomito then gastroenterite.
if dor_de_cabeca and nausea and sensibilidade_a_luz then migranea.
if febre and dor_muscular and dor_de_cabeca and erupcoes_cutaneas then dengue.
if dor_abdominal and febre and nausea and perda_de_apetite then apendicite.
if febre and tosse and dificuldade_respiratoria and dor_no_peito then pneumonia.
if febre and dor_de_cabeca and cansaco and dor_de_garganta and inchaco_nos_ganglios then mono.
if cansaco and aumento_de_peso and intolerancia_ao_frio then hipotireoidismo.
if perda_de_peso and taquicardia and nervosismo and intolerancia_ao_calor then hipertireoidismo.
if sede_excessiva and fome_frequente and urinacao_frequente and perda_de_peso then diabetes.
if dor_lombar and rigidez_muscular then lombalgia.
if erupcoes_cutaneas and coceira and vermelhidao_na_pele then urticaria.
if dor_abdominal and diarreia and perda_de_peso and presenca_de_sangue_nas_fezes then colite_ulcerativa.
if tosse and tosse_prolongada and febre and suores_noturnos and perda_de_peso then tuberculose.
if dor_de_cabeca and tontura and falta_de_ar then hipertensao.
if dificuldade_respiratoria and cansaco and inchaco_nas_pernas and tosse and tosse_seca then insuficiencia_cardiaca.

%Treatments

tratamento(nome_tratamento, [tratamentos], custo, duracao).

tratamento(gripe, [repouso, hidratacao, paracetamol], 7, 7).
tratamento(anemia, [dieta, suplemento_ferro], 15, 15).
tratamento(asma, [inalador], 40, 10).
tratamento(gastroenterite, [hidratacao, dieta], 0, 30).
tratamento(migranea, [aspirina, repouso], 10, 10).
tratamento(dengue, [hidratacao, paracetamol], 3, 15).
tratamento(apendicite, [cirurgia], 1500, 1).
tratamento(pneumonia, [antibiotico], 10, 15).
tratamento(mono, [hidratacao, repouso], 0, 10).
tratamento(hipotireoidismo, [terapia_hormonal], 90, 3).
tratamento(hipertireoidismo, [antitireoidiano], 35, 5).
tratamento(diabetes, [dieta, exercicio, insulina], 15, 5).
tratamento(lombalgia, [fisioterapia, brufen], 10, 15).
tratamento(urticaria, [antihistaminico], 20, 5).
tratamento(colite_ulcerativa, [antiinflamatorio], 15, 7).
tratamento(tuberculose, [antibiotico], 30, 30).
tratamento(hipertensao, [dieta, antihipertensivo], 5, 15).
tratamento(insuficiencia_cardiaca, [dieta, vasodilatador, diuretico], 5, 15).

And this is the code i have in my interface:
:- dynamic (fact/1), [P1].
:- dynamic (demo/1).

%Inciate consultation

iniciar_consulta :-
    retractall(fact(_)),  
    writeln('Bem-vindo ao sistema de diagnostico medico.'),
    writeln('Por favor, responda às seguintes perguntas com 1 (sim) ou 2 (nao):'), perg1.
    
    perg1 :- writeln('Tem febre?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(febre))), perg2.
    perg2 :- writeln('Tem tosse?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(tosse))), perg3.
    perg3 :- writeln('Tem tosse seca?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(tosse_seca))), perg4.
    perg4 :- writeln('Tem tosse prolongada?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(tosse_prolongada))), perg5.
    perg5 :- writeln('Tem cansaço?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(cansaco))), perg6.
    perg6 :- writeln('Tem nervosismo?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(nervosismo))), perg7.
    perg7 :- writeln('Tem naúseas?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(nausea))), perg8.
    perg8 :- writeln('Tem diarreia?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(diarreia))), perg9.
    perg9 :- writeln('Tem vómitos?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(vomito))), perg10.
    perg10 :- writeln('Tem coceira?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(coceira))), perg11.
    perg11 :- writeln('Tem taquicardia?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(taquicardia))), perg12.
    perg12 :- writeln('Tem tonturas?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(tontura))), perg13.
    perg13 :- writeln('Tem dor abdominal?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(dor_abdominal))), perg14.
    perg14 :- writeln('Tem dor de cabeca?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(dor_de_cabeca))), perg15.
    perg15 :- writeln('Tem dor muscular?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(dor_muscular))), perg16.
    perg16 :- writeln('Tem dor no peito?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(dor_no_peito))), perg17.
    perg17 :- writeln('Tem dor de garganta?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(dor_de_garganta))), perg18.
    perg18 :- writeln('Tem dificuldade respiratória?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(dificuldade_respiratoria))), perg19.
    perg19 :- writeln('Tem rigidez muscular?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(rigidez_muscular))), perg20.
    perg20 :- writeln('Tem perda de apetite?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(perda_de_apetite))), perg21.
    perg21 :- writeln('Tem inchaço nos gânglios?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(inchaco_nos_ganglios))), perg22.
    perg22 :- writeln('Tem inchaço nas pernas?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(inchaco_nas_pernas))), perg23.
    perg23 :- writeln('Tem erupções cutâneas?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(erupcoes cutaneas))), perg24.
    perg24 :- writeln('Tem vermelhidão na pele?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(vermelhidao_na_pele))), perg25.
    perg25 :- writeln('Tem sensibilidade à luz?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(sensibilidade_a_luz))), perg26.
    perg26 :- writeln('Tem perdido peso?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(perda_de_peso))), perg27.
    perg27 :- writeln('Tem ganho peso?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(aumento_de_peso))), perg28.
    perg28 :- writeln('Tem intolerância ao frio?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(intolerancia_ao_frio))), perg29.
    perg29 :- writeln('Tem intolerância_ao_calor?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(intolerancia_ao_calor))), perg30.
    perg30 :- writeln('Tem urinado frequentemente?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(urinacao_frequente))), perg31.
    perg31 :- writeln('Tem sede excessiva?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(sede_excessiva))), perg32.
    perg32 :- writeln('Tem fome frequente?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(fome_frequente))), perg33.
    perg33 :- writeln('Tem presenca de sangue nas fezes?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(presenca_de_sangue_nas_fezes))), perg34.
    perg34 :- writeln('Tem suores noturnos?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(suores_noturnos))), perg35.
    perg35 :- writeln('Tem falta de ar?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(falta_de_ar))).
    
    
%Diagnosting the disease 

doenca :-
    demo(X),
    writeln('Baseado nos sintomas fornecidos, pode ter:'),
    writeln(X).

%Providing Treatment

tratamento :-
    fact(X),
    tratamento(Nome_tratamento, [Tratamentos], Custo, Duracao),
    writeln('Tratamento recomendado:'),
    write('Para tratar '),
    write(Nome_tratamento),
    write(' recomendamos o seguinte tratamento: '),
    writeln([Tratamentos]),
    writeln('Este tratamento terá um custo total de: '),
    writeln(Custo),
    writeln('E uma duração (em dias) de: '),
    writeln(Duracao).

%Main Function to Execute Consulation

consulta :-
    iniciar_consulta,
    doenca,
    tratamento.

This is a print of SWI-Prolog when i run the code for reference:
enter image description here

Press key '.' (dot), before ,  for the answer to be read.

This is not a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_reproducible_example
Debug it: https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=debugger

read(S) reads a Prolog term; see the SWI Prolog help: https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=read%2F1 which says:

[NOTE] You might have found this while looking for a predicate to read input from a file or the user. Quite likely this is not what you need in this case. This predicate is for reading a Prolog term which may span multiple lines and must end in a full stop (dot character followed by a layout character).

Try read_line_to_string/2 and then convert string to number, e.g.
?- read_line_to_string(user_input, Str),
   number_string(Num, Str).


I have tried this, and it does not seem to work, maybe I am putting it into my code in a wrong way. Could you provide an example?

That is an example in my answer. The ?- is the Prolog toplevel query prompt, not part of the code. You can copy read_line_to_string(user_input, Str), number_string(Num, Str) into a query on https://swish.swi-prolog.org/ and run it.
